# WSO2 ESB: XSL Transformation Causes an WstxUnexpectedCharException

Tags: xslt, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have a proxy which needs to do XSL transformation of an output message coming from the service. I have attached the sequence file and the XSL file (at synaptic-configs/local-entries).

Appreciate if you can give a hint on where I might have gone wrong.

Here's the sequence file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="EmpMergeOutSeq1" trace="enable" statistics="enable">
    <log level="full">
        <property name="sequence" value="Final Transform using XSLT - begin"/>
    </log>
    <xslt key="getEmployeeByIdResponseXlt"/>
    <send/>
</sequence>
```

Here's the XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="getEmployeeByIdResponseXlt">
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ax21="http://domain.hrapp.gunith/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://service.hrapp.gunith" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="ns fn">
        <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//ns:getEmployeeByIdResponse"/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template xmlns:ns="http://samples.esb.wso2.org" match="ns:getEmployeeByIdResponse">
            <ns1:getEmployeeByIdResponse xmlns:ns1="http://service.proxy.gunith">
                <ns1:return xmlns:ax22="http://domain.proxy.gunith/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax22:Employee">
                    <ax22:dob>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ns:return/ax21:dob"/>
                    </ax22:dob>
                    <ax22:firstName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ns:return/ax21:firstName"/>
                    </ax22:firstName>
                    <ax22:id>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ns:return/ax21:id"/>
                    </ax22:id>
                    <ax22:lastName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ns:return/ax21:lastName"/>
                    </ax22:lastName>
                    <ax22:middleName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ns:return/ax21:middleName"/>
                    </ax22:middleName>
                </ns1:return>
            </ns1:getEmployeeByIdResponse>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</localEntry>
```

Here are the log entries (which shows the Errors and the actual messages passed):

```
[2012-08-04 11:35:44,966]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/MergedBasicEmployeesProxy.MergedBasicEmployeesProxyHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:getEmployeeById, SOAPAction: urn:getEmployeeById, MessageID: urn:uuid:c80fb5a4-41e4-4de4-924d-a18af37b5056, Direction: request, sequence = inSequence - request for EmpMergeProxy, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><p:getEmployeeById xmlns:p="http://service.proxy.gunith"><!--0 to 1 occurrence--><xs:args0 xmlns:xs="http://service.proxy.gunith">1</xs:args0></p:getEmployeeById></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2012-08-04 11:35:44,970]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/MergedBasicEmployeesProxy.MergedBasicEmployeesProxyHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:getEmployeeById, SOAPAction: urn:getEmployeeById, MessageID: urn:uuid:c80fb5a4-41e4-4de4-924d-a18af37b5056, Direction: request, sequence = inSequence - request for EmpMergeProxy, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><sam:getEmployeeById xmlns:sam="http://service.hrapp.gunith">
                <sam:args0>1</sam:args0>
            </sam:getEmployeeById></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2012-08-04 11:35:45,504]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:ea979246-adbc-494d-bd55-e3ed25171984, Direction: response, sequence = Final Transform using XSLT - begin, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ns:getEmployeeByIdResponse xmlns:ns="http://service.hrapp.gunith"><ns:return xmlns:ax21="http://domain.hrapp.gunith/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax21:Employee"><ax21:dob>1984-03-01</ax21:dob><ax21:firstName>Gunith</ax21:firstName><ax21:id>1</ax21:id><ax21:lastName>Dev</ax21:lastName><ax21:middleName>E</ax21:middleName></ns:return></ns:getEmployeeByIdResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2012-08-04 11:35:45,505]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:2eb104c0-53c9-4155-8fef-99e7600b7559, Direction: response, sequence = Final Transform using XSLT - begin, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ns:getEmployeeByIdResponse xmlns:ns="http://service.hrapp.gunith"><ns:return xmlns:ax21="http://domain.hrapp.gunith/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax21:Employee"><ax21:dob>1984-03-01</ax21:dob><ax21:firstName>Gunith</ax21:firstName><ax21:id>1</ax21:id><ax21:lastName>Dev</ax21:lastName><ax21:middleName>E</ax21:middleName></ns:return></ns:getEmployeeByIdResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2012-08-04 11:35:45,528] ERROR - XSLTMediator Unable to perform XSLT transformation using : Value {name ='null', keyValue ='getEmployeeByIdResponseXlt'} against source XPath : s11:Body/child::*[position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[position()=1]
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '1' (code 49) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
    at org.apache.synapse.util.jaxp.StreamResultBuilder.getNode(StreamResultBuilder.java:87)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator.performXSLT(XSLTMediator.java:298)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator.mediate(XSLTMediator.java:191)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:60)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:229)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:370)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:275)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:173)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is at your xslt script..What you can do is try in eclipse/any other xslt processor feed the soap message as input xml for this xslt script and run..If the script is right, you will get output else not...

Comment: Thanks for the help! Found the issue. Like you said I had a problem with the XML. VERY careful inspection helped me find it.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across a similar issue before. It was usually when dealing with namespaces during XSLT transformation. WSO2 by default uses xalan.jar as xml parser, it got to be replaced by saxon9he.jar. Following URL for your reference ["How to change the XSLT processor"](http://heshans.blogspot.in/2011/07/changing-underlying-xslt-processor-of.html)

Thanks.